# GIT Permissions

Tags: git, version-control, github

There is something not clear for me and this is how to prevent other people read my code. The thing is that I want people create their own branches but not to view the other's branches. If someone is responsible for networking, I don't want this guy to view graphics codes. S/He must be forced to work on his branch only.

Comment: Identical question posted by same user: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/204676/git-permissions

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. For one, branches are *not* for separating parts of the entire program; they are only for keeping multiple series of changes separate until they get merged to the master branch, and they will all contain the *entire* tree of files in that repository. For another, to work with a Git *at all*, a developer needs to clone the entire repository from the server first.

If there are several parts that absolutely must be kept separate <sup>*(even though I do not understand that)*</sup>, you should keep them in separate Git repositories.

Comment: For those interested in keeping separate repositories for a single project [my answer on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/204676/git-permissions) may be of interest.